# Xamarin forms IOS Buttons looking distorted

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have the following XAML code below :

```
    <StackLayout
        Grid.Row="2"
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        VerticalOptions="End"
        Margin="0,0,0,20"
        Spacing="28">

        <Button
            x:Name="SignInButton"
            Visual="Material"
            Padding="5"
            Margin="10,0,0,0"
            Style="{DynamicResource ButtonSecondary}"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"              
            Text="Sign In"
            Clicked="SignInButton_Clicked"/>

        <Button
            x:Name="JoinUsButton"
            Visual="Material"
            Padding="5"
            Margin="0,0,10,0"
            Style="{DynamicResource ButtonPrimary}"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="End"
            Text="Join Us"
            Clicked="JoinUsButton_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

The dynamic resources currently stored in the App.xaml file are as follows :

```
<Style x:Name="ButtonSecondary" x:Key="ButtonSecondary" TargetType="Button" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
            Value="{DynamicResource SecondaryColor}" />
    <Setter Property="TextColor"
            Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryTextColor}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderWidth"
            Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderColor"
            Value="{DynamicResource SecondaryBorderColor}" />
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius"
            Value="50" />            
</Style>
```

However, when I run the app on iOS the buttons look like the image below.

[image: iPhone 12 Pro Max]

However, on the android device, the buttons look like the image below :

[image]

Comment: Does it work now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cauuse :** In iOS , if you want to achieve the effect like the above image which you get in Android , you need to set the **CornerRadius** as half of its **HeightRequest**  .

**Solution**

**Option 1**

If the size of the button is always a fixed value , you just need to set the **HeightRequest** in the style

```
<Style x:Name="ButtonSecondary" x:Key="ButtonSecondary" TargetType="Button" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
            Value="{DynamicResource SecondaryColor}" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor"
            Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryTextColor}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderWidth"
            Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="BorderColor"
            Value="{DynamicResource SecondaryBorderColor}" />
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius"
            Value="25" />
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest"
            Value="50" />  // double of CornerRadius
        </Style>
```

**Option 2 :**

If the size of Button will change in runtime , you could use **Custom Renderer** to set the `CornerRadius`  in iOS platform .

#### in Forms

create a custom button

```
public class MyButton:Button
{
}
```

#### in iOS

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UIKit;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using App6;
using App6.iOS;
using System.ComponentModel;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MyButton),typeof(MyButtonRenderer))]
namespace App6.iOS
{
    public  class MyButtonRenderer:ButtonRenderer
    {
       
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if(e.PropertyName=="Height")
            {
                var height = Element.Height;

                Control.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
                Control.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
                Control.Layer.CornerRadius = (nfloat)(height / 2.0);
                Control.Layer.BorderWidth = (nfloat)0.5;

            }

        }
    }
}
```

#### in xaml

```
<local:MyButton
            x:Name="SignInButton"
            Visual="Material"
            Padding="5"
            Margin="10,0,0,0"
            Style="{DynamicResource ButtonSecondary}"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"              
            Text="Sign In"
           />
```

[image]

Comment: @George You could check my answer .

Answer (score 0):

While I can't see the exact issue you are seeing with the distortion I do see an inconsistency between platforms. This ultimately comes down to how the individual platforms render the `CornerRadius` property. **Android** will limit it to what is visibly sensible (basically half the height/width, whichever is smaller) whereas **iOS** will just do as you ask.

This image shows on the left what I currently see, the middle is my second solution and the right is my first solution.

[image: Issue I see plus solutions]

My possible solutions are:

### Attach a Behavior

```
public class RoundCornerBehavior : Behavior<Button>
{
    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Button button)
    {
        button.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
        base.OnAttachedTo(button);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Button button)
    {
        button.SizeChanged -= OnSizeChanged;
        base.OnDetachingFrom(button);
    }

    private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button) sender;
        button.CornerRadius = (int)Math.Min(button.Width, button.Height) / 2;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty AttachBehaviorProperty =
            BindableProperty.CreateAttached("AttachBehavior", typeof(bool), typeof(RoundCornerBehavior), false, propertyChanged: OnAttachBehaviorChanged);

    public static bool GetAttachBehavior(BindableObject view)
    {
        return (bool)view.GetValue(AttachBehaviorProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAttachBehavior(BindableObject view, bool value)
    {
        view.SetValue(AttachBehaviorProperty, value);
    }

    static void OnAttachBehaviorChanged(BindableObject view, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (!(view is Button button))
        {
            return;
        }

        var attachBehavior = (bool)newValue;
        if (attachBehavior)
        {
            button.Behaviors.Add(new RoundCornerBehavior());
        }
        else
        {
            var toRemove = button.Behaviors.FirstOrDefault(b => b is RoundCornerBehavior);
            if (toRemove != null)
            {
                button.Behaviors.Remove(toRemove);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then simply attach in your style:

`<Setter Property="roundButton:RoundCornerBehavior.AttachBehavior" Value="true" />`

I would suggest writing some kind of `Behavior` to provide the sensible `CornerRadius` which would essentially take the `Width` and `Height` properties of the control and simply set the `CornerRadius` to half the smallest value. I will see if I can knock something up to provide a concrete example shortly.

**The nice result of this approach will allow you to continue to define the controls as you were previously and keep the logic self contained in the attached behavior.**

### Sub class button

An alternative would be to sub class `Button` and created your own `RoundedButton` that could do the same as the `Behavior` approach. Then

```
public class RoundedButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

        this.CornerRadius = (int)Math.Min(width, height) / 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was marked down, and I am just trying to wrap my mind around your answer

Comment: @George me neither, I appreciate I hadn't supplied an example but I have added 2 now :)